# Use Android Fabric Crashlytics with different API keys on each process

Tags: android, crashlytics, crashlytics-android

We have an Android library that does all its work in a separate process (uses a `Service` with `android:process` tag in the manifest) and I'm trying to use Fabric.io crash reporting on it.

Currently we're also developing an app for 3rd party that uses the library, so it's a good moment to test it out.

Currently I've added the Fabric crashlytics to the app main process itself using the standard way:

```
Fabric.with(this, new Crashlytics());
```

and this picks up the API key from the manifest.

My issue is that there's no constructor or builder that I can specify a different API key for the other process, or even if I wanted to use the same API key just for this project, I haven't seen anywhere that multi-process is officially supported (and as far as I saw using Android Studio decompiler, it seems Fabric saves as files on disk which doesn't seem very appropriate for multi-process application).

The only maybe, possible path I've found is to pass a ContextWrapper to the Fabric initialisation and intercept the api key there. But that's just sounds like a lot of room for error.

So questions:

- is there a way to init Fabric/Crashlitics with an chosen api key? How?
- if I can't init with apiKey, is it safe to use it in multi-process? Can I use in this 1-off app?

Comment: Mike from Fabric here. Fabric cannot be used in libraries that will be distributed to third party apps. Do not include Fabric or the apps that use your library will have problems if they choose to include Fabric.

Comment: hi @MikeBonnell thanks for the reply. I understand the implications of having 2 crash reporting tools in 1 process. They'll interfere with each other UncaughtExceptionHandler, fabric disk cache of events probably will have collisions, plus there would be stacktrace from the app. But I'll like to point again that this library runs on its own process totally separated from the app and I would of course only init Fabric on the library process. I've been checking others and it seems that hockey CrashManager can easily be used on my process but their UI is crap and I rather use fabric =/

Comment: Definitely understand your desires. It remains though that we don't recommend this setup.